# Aggregating in Base R?

Tags: r, aggregate, transpose

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = sample(1:100, 64),
                 Facility=rep(c("A","B","C","D"), each=4, times=4), 
                 MMWR = rep(c("1503","1504","1505", "1506"), 16), 
                 Age = sample(1:4, 64, replace=TRUE))


    ID  Facility    MMWR    Age
1   86  A   1503    4
2   85  A   1504    3
3   37  A   1505    1
4   77  A   1506    1
5   73  B   1503    2
6   40  B   1504    2
7   2   B   1505    3
8   97  B   1506    3
9   83  C   1503    4
10  80  C   1504    4
11  69  C   1505    3
12  93  C   1506    3
13  56  D   1503    3
14  12  D   1504    4
15  1   D   1505    2
16  72  D   1506    1
17  90  A   1503    1
18  95  A   1504    2
19  78  A   1505    4
20  98  A   1506    2
21  68  B   1503    2
22  38  B   1504    4
23  21  B   1505    2
24  3   B   1506    2
25  16  C   1503    4
26  74  C   1504    2
27  27  C   1505    4
28  6   C   1506    2
29  64  D   1503    1
30  59  D   1504    3
31  65  D   1505    3
32  53  D   1506    4
33  9   A   1503    1
34  22  A   1504    1
35  62  A   1505    1
36  26  A   1506    2
37  31  B   1503    3
38  100 B   1504    2
39  47  B   1505    1
40  36  B   1506    3
41  60  C   1503    3
42  18  C   1504    2
43  10  C   1505    3
44  51  C   1506    3
45  44  D   1503    3
46  54  D   1504    4
47  76  D   1505    3
48  67  D   1506    3
49  28  A   1503    1
50  58  A   1504    4
51  23  A   1505    1
52  71  A   1506    1
53  20  B   1503    3
54  32  B   1504    4
55  84  B   1505    4
56  33  B   1506    4
57  50  C   1503    1
58  61  C   1504    2
59  25  C   1505    3
60  91  C   1506    1
61  17  D   1503    2
62  81  D   1504    4
63  48  D   1505    4
64  24  D   1506    4
```

I'd like to aggregate (and/or tranpose?) to get the number of each age in separate columns. For the above dataset, I want the following output

```
    Facility    MMWR    Age 1   Age 2   Age 3   Age 4
1   A   1503    3   0   0   1
2   A   1504    1   1   1   1
3   A   1505    3   0   0   1
4   A   1506    2   2   0   0
5   B   1503    0   2   2   0
6   B   1504    0   2   0   2
7   B   1505    1   1   1   1
8   B   1506    0   1   2   1
9   C   1503    1   0   1   2
10  C   1504    0   3   0   1
11  C   1505    0   0   3   1
12  C   1506    1   1   2   0
13  D   1503    1   1   2   0
14  D   1504    0   0   1   3
15  D   1505    0   1   2   1
16  D   1506    1   0   1   2
```

PLEASE NOTE THAT I WILL ONLY BE ABLE TO USE BASE R!

Will put the long winded solution I've come up with in the comments, but I'm hoping someone can give me something better...

Comment: Your code for the dataset is not consistent with the data set. Where is `ID` ?

Answer (score 4):

Using Only base R, `reshape` and `aggregate` will do the trick.

```
reshape(aggregate(ID ~ Facility + MMWR + Age, data = df, length), 
    idvar = c('Facility', 'MMWR'), 
    direction = 'wide', 
    v.name = 'ID', 
    timevar = 'Age')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I used to generate the answer; just would like to find something much cleaner and without so much repetition since in reality I'll have many many more groups... Thanks!

```
blah1 = aggregate( ID ~ Facility + MMWR, data = (subset(df, Age == "1")), length)
colnames(blah1)[3] = "Age 1"

blah2 = aggregate( ID ~ Facility + MMWR, data = (subset(df, Age == "2")), length)
colnames(blah2)[3] = "Age 2"

blah3 = aggregate( ID ~ Facility + MMWR, data = (subset(df, Age == "3")), length)
colnames(blah3)[3] = "Age 3"

blah4 = aggregate( ID ~ Facility + MMWR, data = (subset(df, Age == "4")), length)
colnames(blah4)[3] = "Age 4"


blah5 = merge(blah1, blah2, by = c("Facility", "MMWR"), all=TRUE)
blah6 = merge(blah5, blah3, by = c("Facility", "MMWR"), all=TRUE)
blah7 = merge(blah6, blah4, by = c("Facility", "MMWR"), all=TRUE)
blah7[is.na(blah7)] = 0

blah = blah7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `aggregate` without subsetting and `reshape`, but I prefer `xtabs` here.

```
ftable(xtabs(Count~Facility+MMWR+Age,data=transform(df,Count=1)))
```

```
              Age 1 2 3 4
Facility MMWR            
A        1503     3 0 0 1
         1504     1 1 1 1
         1505     3 0 0 1
         1506     2 2 0 0
B        1503     0 2 2 0
         1504     0 2 0 2
         1505     1 1 1 1
         1506     0 1 2 1
C        1503     1 0 1 2
         1504     0 3 0 1
         1505     0 0 3 1
         1506     1 1 2 0
D        1503     1 1 2 0
         1504     0 0 1 3
         1505     0 1 2 1
         1506     1 0 1 2
```

Already gives the results, but in the `ftable` class. To convert to a `data.frame` we do some manual coercion.

```
reshape.ftable<-function(ft) {    
  a<-attributes(ft)
  x<-data.frame(expand.grid(rev(a$row.vars)), unclass(ft))
  colnames(x)<-c(names(rev(a$row.vars)),
    unlist(lapply(a$col.vars,function(x) paste(names(a$col.vars),x,sep="."))))
  x
}
```

Final result

```
reshape.ftable(ftable(xtabs(Count~Facility+MMWR+Age,data=transform(df,Count=1))))
```

```
   MMWR Facility Age.1 Age.2 Age.3 Age.4
1  1503        A     3     0     0     1
2  1504        A     1     1     1     1
3  1505        A     3     0     0     1
4  1506        A     2     2     0     0
5  1503        B     0     2     2     0
6  1504        B     0     2     0     2
7  1505        B     1     1     1     1
8  1506        B     0     1     2     1
9  1503        C     1     0     1     2
10 1504        C     0     3     0     1
11 1505        C     0     0     3     1
12 1506        C     1     1     2     0
13 1503        D     1     1     2     0
14 1504        D     0     0     1     3
15 1505        D     0     1     2     1
16 1506        D     1     0     1     2
```

Comment: maybe its in the last step, but I don't think the final table yields the right results? the numbers in each age column are identical to my output, but the order of the facility and MMWR is not correct...